# Vue component not showing vue js

Tags: vue.js

This is my header.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>this is header h2</h2>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Header',
  data () {
    return {
      data: 'this is header'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is my HelloWorld.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <header/>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

import Header from './Header'  
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  //после того как импортировали компоент - вот здесь указываем его явно:
  components: {
      Header
    },
  data () {

    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is my folder structure:

[image]

But the header component is not showing - no errors, just not showing. What do I do??

Comment: What's in your `main.js`? You have two templates, but you need a main page where you tell Vue to go ahead and render itself out (e.g. `import HelloWorld from "/HelloWorld.vue"; new Vue({ el: '#main', render: h => h(HelloWorld) });`

Comment: Can you provide use your `App.vue` and `main.js`?

Answer (score 0):

If you define your component like this:

```
components: {
  Header
},
```

call it inside your template like this: `<Header />` with capitalize.

<del>If you want to use kebab-case like: `<header></header>`, define your component like this:</del>

```
components: {
  'header': Header
},
```

---

**Edit**
According to @MaxLyashuk comment, the naming convention for Vue component ([source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Name-Casing)) is case-insensitive in that case.

The fact that `<Header />` capitalized worked is because `<header>` is a reserved word for html markup.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can register the component as `Header` and use as `header` or as `Header` it will work! It works the same way as html. The html is case-insensitive.

Comment: Passing `Header` into your components property, you can use it asa <header> in your template. The reason why it doesn't show is basically the header tag is built-in. He should rename his component into something else or prefix it like what others do.